# Add rows into Database table using Shell Script?

Tags: postgresql, shell

How to add rows into table in the Database by Shell Script?
I have following:

```
Postgres Database Name: dm
Table Name: Error Codes
Password of Database: ******
```

I want to add rows into table?

I am just starting Shell Scripting...

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATABASE="dm"
USERNAME="postgres"
HOSTNAME="HBG"
export PGPASSWORD="postgres"

psql -h $HOSTNAME -U $USERNAME $DATABaSE << EOF
select * from Error Codes
EOF
```

Getting error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "HBG" (192.168.0.241) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on how to use the [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-psql.html) command.

You can state any SQL query using this command. For example:

```
psql -c "SELECT * FROM foo" mydatabase myusername
```

Of course you can also use `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and all other SQL commands, as long as `myusername` has the rights to do so.

If you want to do this WITHOUT a password (but this is strongly disrecommended and unsecure) you can add this at the start of your script:

```
set PGPASSWORD=<password>
```

See here for full documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-psql.html

Comment: I am getting thid error:- `Is the server running on host "abc" (192.168.1.241) and accepting`

Comment: What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Plz can you see question again, I update code in it??

Comment: `HOsTNAME` -> linux is case sensitive... You use `$HOSTNAME` and declare `$HOsTNAME`. So `$HOSTNAME` is undefined. Also, is the server actually accepting connections that do not originate from localhost? If not -> Thats a question for ServerFault.

Comment: Edited previous comment

Comment: Did you read the last part? Is the server even configured to accept connection that do not originate from localhost? Is the port correct? If one of that are the issues, its stuff for ServerFault.